# Using Socket.io, how do I detect when a new channel/room has been created?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

From the server, I want to be able to detect when a client creates new a room or channel. The catch is that the rooms and channels are arbitrary so i don't know what they will be until the user joins/subscribes. Something like this:

Server:

```
io.on('created', function (room) {
    console.log(room); //prints "party-channel-123"
});
```

Client:

```
socket.on('party-channel-123', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

I also can't have any special client requirements such as sending a message when the channel is subscribed as such:

```
socket.on('party-channel-123', function (data) {
    socket.emit('subscribed', 'party-channel-123');
})
```

Comment: Emit a "newRoom" event and catch it?

Comment: I don't think users can create **channels** ; they can only create **rooms,** right?

Comment: @JakeSellers, I need this to work without emitting any special events.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD, when a user subscribes with socket.on, are they not, necessarily, creating a new channel?

Comment: @jwanga No, according to the source, channels deal with endpoints *(or paths).* Rooms are much different. A single channel can have multiple rooms :).

Comment: @jwanga My bad; I confused channels with namespaces. Channels are rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('createRoom', function(roomName) {
        socket.join(roomName);
    });
});
```

Client

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.emit('createRoom', 'roomName');
```

the `io` object has references to all currently created rooms and can be used as such:

```
io.sockets.in(room).emit('event', data);
```

Hope this helps.

PS. I know its emitting the 'createRoom' that you probably don't want but this is how socket.io is used, this is pretty much copy/paste out of the docs.  There are tons of examples on the socket.io website and others.